# Checking if userinput is a valid URI in XUL

Tags: javascript, validation, firefox, xul

Is there a built-in function/method that can check if a given string is a valid URI or not in the [Mozilla XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL) toolkit? I have looked for one but found none, but since this is my first time using XUL and its documentation it could be that I just overlooked it. So I'm just making sure before I start writing my own `IsValidURI` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [nsIIOService.newURI(...)](http://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=En/NsIIOService&highlight=newURI#newURI.28.29) method is what you're looking for. It throws **NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI** if the URI string is invalid.

Example:

```
try {
  var ioServ = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
  var uriObj = ioServ.newURI(uriString, uriCharset, baseURI);
} catch (e) {

  // catch the error here

}
```